# NOAA Forecast data in BigQuery no longer being updated?

Tags: google-bigquery, noaa

Looks like there is no longer data being published to the public NOAA forecast table in bigquery's public dataset. Does anyone know why that is happening? I cannot find any info about the data being discontinued on either website.

> project: bigquery-public-data
>
> dataset: noaa_global_forecast_system
>
> table: NOAA_GFS0P25

BigQuery sql that you can use to test this out:

```
SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.noaa_global_forecast_system.NOAA_GFS0P25` WHERE DATE(creation_time) >= "2022-04-11" LIMIT 100
```

New forecast data has not been inserted into the table since 4/10/22. They have missed a day before, but we have not seen them miss multiple days in a row before. We would like to know if we need to migrate to a new forecast source, but we cannot find any info on whether this one is being shut down or if they are just having temporary technical difficulties.

Comment: You can raise a ticket to request for an update in public dataset in this [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: I have submitted a case with google. There were unfortunately no issue trackers for this data set. I have also emailed webmaster@noaa.gov and ums.hdq.ocio@noaa.gov (office of the CIO of NOAA) but have not gotten a reply.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a problem with a data source, should be raised with the data provider not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the heads up! This looks like a temporary technical issue, but we are working on getting this dataset back up and running.

Comment: Thanks for the response Shane. If there could be a contact page or some sort of status page for this, that would be great. There is nothing online about this, and that would be really helpful in the future.

Comment: Happy to help. You can always reach out with questions to public-data-help@google.com. We've identified the specific issue and have resolved the blocker. It will take a bit for the backlog to clear, but you should start seeing new data in BigQuery soon. Long-term, we are working on a public status page as well as migrating this to the architecture you can review in our public GitHub repo